# How can i make OR operator in query params in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, filtering, django-rest-framework

If i need to do filtering in django rest then i usually do this

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_type='lte')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'in_stock', 'min_price', 'max_price']

class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

I can use like

`http://example.com/api/products?category=clothing&max_price=10.00`

But this will do `AND`

How can i do that OR from url like

where `(category = clothing || max_price = 10)`

Basically i should be able to provide all params in URL like

```
http://example.com/api/products? AND=[{category: clothing}, {age: 10}], OR=[{age_gte:10}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, you need to pass in your url some flag to check if you want to perform a mixed query. Also add a prefix to params, if `age=20` should be used in the AND operator, add prefix 'and_', it looks like `and_age=20` and so on. The same for OR params.

Let's have this url

```
http://example.com/api/products?and_category=clothing&and_max_price=10.00&or_age=20&mixed=true
```

Now, our view.

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_class = ProductFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        data = self.request.DATA
        mixed_query = data.get('mixed',None)
        
        if not mixed_query:
            return self.queryset
        and_params = {}
        for key in data:
           if 'and_' in key:
              and_params[key] = data[key]
        
        
        queryset = Products.objects.filter(**and_params)
        for key in self.request.DATA:
            if 'or_' in key:
              queryset = queryset | Products.objects.filter(key=data[key])

        return queryset
```

**NOTE: `request.DATA` has been deprecated in favor of `request.data` since version 3.0**

Comment: but how to pass parametera in query and how will the system know whch parameters are AND and which are OR. basically i want to do all filtering by passing them in query. i won't know before hand which parameters . so i want to generalize

Comment: @user3214546 you need to overide your get_queryset view function, extract params from request and make the query by yourself. Let me update my answer.

Comment: thanks for that but i can't hard code the fields because they can be any . it should be dynamically able to AND and OR or any fields

Comment: @user3214546 it's a good point; I guess a URL structure will struggle with nested logic (which is required when mixing AND an OR).

Comment: @user3214546 check my answer again, I updated it, now you can use any params.